# Express server response is a stream, how to make it a string / json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response

I am `POST`ing data to my `express` (v.4+) server. However, the response I get back in the browser is in the form:

`Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:1111/", status: 200, ok: true, …}`

Specifically, the `body` of response is a `ReadbleStream`, instead of `json` or `string` I expected as per the response I am sending back.

The server code is:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/block');
const app = express();
app.set('port', 1111);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => { // for cors
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { dataType, table } = req.body;
  const { rows } = table;
  const log = {
    msgArray: []
  };
  function saveData(dbModel) {
    rows.forEach(row => {
      row.data_initiated = new Date();
      row.status = 'initiated';
      const entry = new dbModel(row);
      entry.save(err => {
        if (err) {
          log.msgArray.push({ err });
        }
        log.msgArray.push({
          msg: 'saved!'
        });
      });
    });
  }
  if (dataType === 'Contract') {
    saveData(Contract);
  } else if (dataType === 'Commodity') {
    saveData(Commodity);
  } else {
    saveData(Client);
  }
  res.send(log).end();
```

I am using `fetch` on the client side to `POST` data.

How can I get this to correct send `json / string` back to the user?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `fetch`, the response has to be transformed into `JSON`, & returned back. In the subsequent `then`, the transformed value is available to be used.

```
fetch( url, config)
  .then( res => res.json())
  .then( json => {
    console.log( json );
    ...
  }
```

Its worth mentioning that this is a bit different to how we are used to handling responses when using Axios.js (promise based AJAX library).

P.S: I updated the question to fix the code so that the response is sent correctly.